# bzr: Ignore attributes when committing / pulling

Tags: attributes, executable, bazaar, file-attributes

I have one system with msys2, and another system with Ubuntu.
Files in Unix have the *executable* attribute.
Files in msys2 (NTFS based) do not have the *executable* attribute (although msys2 "fakes" it by looking for the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in the first line of each file, at least for `ls`).

When exchanging files with `bzr` (via `commit`, e.g.), I would like `bzr` to ignore the executable attribute as a parameter for determining what to commit. Otherwise, when committing from my msys2 system I would mess the repository.

**Is this possible?**

**EDIT**:
Actually, msys2 does not have other attributes as well, so I would like to ignore all that differs from Unix.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, Bazaar ignores the executable bit based on the sys.platform variable. However, apparently that's not set to *win32* on msys2 but to *msys2*. You can manually fix this in Bazaar by changing the **supports_executable()** function in *bzrlib/osutils.py* from:

```
return sys.platform != "win32"
```

to

```
return sys.platform not in ("win32", "msys", "msys2")
```

Newer versions of [Breezy](https://www.breezy-vcs.org/), the successor to Bazaar, address this by not reading the executable bit from the filesystem if the filesystem (e.g. FAT, NTFS, etc) does not support executable bits  rather than checking **sys.platform**.

Comment: So you mean that I will constantly have that problem with bzr-msys2 <-> bzr<->Linux?
Any workaround?

Comment: Actually, it looks like this is something specific to msys2. Updated my comment.

Comment: 1) I guess your changed line should be negated to match the behavior above, is that correct?
2) I did not get the outcome. Do you mean that, by default, bzr in Windows already does what I intend, but I should only implement the change you suggested to get the intended behaviour in msys2?

Comment: Your answer is very interesting, as it likely applies to other apps in msys2

Comment: In my case, `sys.platform` is `'msys'`.

Comment: Oops, yes - I've updated it to negate. Thanks. The default installer for Bazaar on Windows already behaves this way, but msys2 apparently identifies itself as a different platform, which is why the behaviour doesn't kick in.